# What is "Transitive induction"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, induction

In the book 
"Artinian Modules Over Group Rings" By Leonid Kurdachenko, Javier Otal, Igor Ya Subbotin
(also see http://books.google.com/)
one can read (on p.117) "applying transitive induction, we obtain ..."

So what is "transitive induction"?

I guess (not from reading the above-mentioned book), that the Principle of Transitive Induction 
may mean the following.

Let $R$ be a binary relation on a set $A$, $R^*$ - the transitive closure of $R$, $B$ - a subset of $A$,

X = $\{z:A | (\exists x:B) R^*(x,z) \}$.

Then to prove a formula of the form

$(\forall z:X) Q(z)$

it is sufficiently to prove the following two formulae:

a) $(\forall z:B) Q(z)$; (the basis of induction)

b) $(\forall z:X, z_1 :A)(R(z,z1) \rightarrow Q(z_1))$. (the inductive step)

Comment: You're sure it's not *transfinite* induction (by spelling or semantic or both)?

Comment: In the book is written "transitive induction".

Comment: In the context, actually, it doesn't look like it is using transfinite induction.

Comment: See here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.5917&rep=rep1&type=pdf